# Easy function but result only with a print?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm learning functions and I don't understand why I have this: we are taught to use "return" instead of "print" to be able to use the function in several cases.

Except that in the basic functions below, the return doesn't show any result, but if I replace the return by a "print", I get the result.

How to display the result of the return without a print? I can't find a solution

```
def el_divisor(number_1, number_2):
  return (number_1 / number_2)

el_divisor(5, 2)


def el_additionator(number_1, number_2):
  return (number_1 + number_2)

el_additionator(5,  2)


def substraction(nb, nb_to_substract):
  return (nb - nb_to_substract)

substraction(5, 2)
```

Comment: `print(substraction(5, 2))` ... since you return it ... you need to print what is returned ...

Comment: Use print() when you are calling the function like, print(subtraction(5,2)), print(e1_divisor(5,2)), etc

Comment: 4 spaces per tab or the PEP8 police will come after you

Comment: Please look into this [Return vs Print](https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/518ffbfeb3f05c44fe001395)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Kindly do like below.

```
def el_divisor(number_1, number_2):
  return (number_1 / number_2)

print(el_divisor(5, 2))


def el_additionator(number_1, number_2):
  return (number_1 + number_2)

print(el_additionator(5,  2))


def substraction(nb, nb_to_substract):
  return (nb - nb_to_substract)

print(substraction(5, 2))
```

Comment: Hey ! I'm sorry for answering so lately, and you were right I had to do it that way.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Using Ipython IDE like will help you.